# How to read content in Facebook's social plugin in iPhone?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I use Facebook's comment social plugin in my website, and now I'd like to go further integrate  it to iPhone app.

Is there any possible way to read the content of the comments in my website by Facebook's iPhone SDK?

Comment: Yes.  Use graph API.  Check out this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/

Comment: Thanks! FB also announce the new comment graph api yesterday: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fyi:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490

now we can use graph api to extract the comment:

Comments for every URL can be accessed via the Graph API:

https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}